# Free extra baggage with trans-Atlantic flights with KLM?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, klm

Since only US citizen are allowed in from Europe at the moment, trans-Atlantic flight will likely have very light planes, no?
I'm wondering if KLM airline would be willing to be lenient with extra baggage and not ask customers to pay extra?

Comment: I doubt that very much given the enormous losses that the airline industry is suffering.

Comment: right :/ ah well. I was just shocked to hear from peers that nearly all airlines and travel agencies are giving refunds for customers canceling their trips. So I thought the "keep loyal customers" mentality that seems to be floating around would extend to leniency across the board *shrug*

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154854/why-is-there-a-weight-limit-for-carry-on-luggage-on-some-airlines-that-is-enforc

Comment: Extra luggage = extra fuel.  This is why the airlines charge more.  So if you take more luggage this means more cost for them, which they will likely continue to pass on to their customers.

Comment: My understanding is that freight demand remains stable. Passenger airliners can carry extra belly freight when they are lightly loaded upstairs. So the premise of this question is not correct.

Comment: Airlines have adjusted their programs to the demand, so it’s not obvious the few remaining flights are as empty as you’d want to think. There are plenty of US citizens and PRs trying to get home.

Comment: Hmmmm this is also true! i gues i underestimate the # of expats!

Comment: 1) Are you interested in KLM only or all airlines? 2) what kind of proof do you want for an answer that satisfies you?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt KLM only, our scholarship program can connections to them.

Comment: @LopeyTall just asked a friend of mine who flew KLM to the US a couple of days ago, and her reply was that they were strict on both hold and carryon baggage weights.

Comment: Top! Thanks @Moo feel free to post as an answer to get some reputation! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Converting a comment to an answer after positive feedback...*

I have just asked a friend of mine who flew KLM to the US a couple of days ago, and her reply was that they were strict on both hold and carryon baggage weights, so it does not look like KLM are relaxing restrictions at this time.